# Exporting data is not in proper format

Tags: php, wordpress, export

I am exporting all data from database.

Like joining 3 tables.

I want to replace column Assigned_to data (183) with user_login( raghu)

But if i do the below code its getting added instead of replaced

$col_final= All the column Names

$row[$j]= all the data

```
if($col_final[$j] == "assigned_to")
{
$result3 = $wpdb->get_results("select user_login from wp3_users where id=".$row[$j].";");
foreach ($result3 as $res3){
$columnList3 = $res3->user_login;
}
$schema_insert .= $columnList3.$sep;    
}
```

output
[image]

expected output
[image]
I tried to replace assigned_to (183,183,246) to user_login name(Raghu,Raghu,Joseph)

But its getting added to assigned _to row not replacing

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: @RajeshPatel I am sorry for that its a huge code so i could paste here....Thing i have joined 2 tables here.i want to replace assigned_to which  contains all the integer to Names(User_Login)

Comment: the columns is not getting replaced